# Is there a way to dynamically type section of a TypeScript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to have a TypeScript object be extended by a type. For example:

```
interface BaseInterface<T> {
  staticA: string;
  staticB: number;
  dynamicA: T;
}

BaseInterface<SomeOtherInterfaceOrType>
```

When used like so, it should define `dynamicA` type as `SomeOtherInterfaceOrType`.

How can this behaviour be achieved? How can I create another interface that is of that type?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#reusable-types-type-aliases) are your friend:
You can create type aliases using syntax similar to variable declaration. This way, you can permanently fix your generic interface to a concrete type, and this can be done an infinite amount of times, for any type matching T (in this case, because T isn't constrained - any type). Generic types are just type/interface factories.

```js
interface BaseInterface<T> {
  staticA: string;
  staticB: number;
  dynamicA: T;
}

type ConstrainedToSymbol = BaseInterface<Symbol>;
// mostly equivalent interface fixing:
interface ConstrainedToNumber extends BaseInterface<number> {}

type ConstrainedToString = BaseInterface<string>;

function func(cbs: ConstrainedToString):string {
 return cbs.dynamicA // Always a string!
}
```

Check out this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QJLmvJAHgBUA+ZAbwChlkMw4xgEBBALjrClAHMBuGp0bNUHEAFcAtgCNoA2gBMAniDiTm7ZMQEBfKlTBKADigDCAexD0ocUBAXFzAZSUzzAG2QBeNJhx5YRAhCFzd3UgEAekjkCABHcWAANzh3CHBkUEhApGQYYAAPXjYqLPwg5AsrLlsQe0cAOSlZKFiCyBAFDF8sXGyCYIkZaHIKPQNjM0trWvrnLl5vHv9+oMJrXgj9GHEQBCZLPN2EAAoEaQwOKpm7B3nuEB4ASjYNx8oaKAgwcSgQZHOGAAdMpVOpWMhosgWO4AO5wJTdOCcB48ACEVB0QA).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. I was standing right on top of the answer it seems and just needed a little nudge, thanks.